# Perl PPM failing to install MinGW

Tags: perl, proxy, connection, mingw

I am trying to run a Perl script that uses the module `Archive::Extract` to extract a `.zip` file.  The problem is every time I run it I keep getting the following error:

ex:

`perl -e "use Archive::Extract"`

> It looks like you don't have a C compiler on your PATH, so you will not be
>   able to compile C or XS extension modules.  You can install GCC from the
>   MinGW package using the Perl Package Manager by running:
>   **ppm install MinGW**

---

Then when I try to fix this error by running the following command I get this:

`ppm install MinGW`

> Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...failed 500 Can't connect to ppm4.activestate.com:80 (10060)
>
> ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW

---

I looked online to find a solution to this problem, but everything says it's a proxy issue and you need to set the `http_proxy` environment variable to solve the problem.  The problem is I can't seem to find any of my proxy settings (The PCs where I work are pretty locked down with security).

I did some research [here](https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using) and I found one command that gave me a result, but i'm not certain it is accurate judging by the comments below the answer.

The command gives me the following results:

`netsh winhttp show proxy`

> Current WinHTTP proxy settings:
>
> Direct access (no proxy server).

---

**How can I get this to connect properly?**